# A mathematical question on an Ultrasonic flow meter (Time of flight)

Tags: flow, instrument

I'm trying gain a better understanding of expressions used to derive a formula to calculate the flow velocity

[image: Ultrasonic Time of Flight Flow Meter]

Here are the following expressions:

$$t_d=  \frac{L}{(v+ucosθ)}$$
$$t_u=  \frac{L}{(v-ucosθ)}$$

$u$ = flow velocity

$v$ = velocity of sound

I'm aware that the upstream flow is combined with the velocity of the sound for $t_d$ which is why they add and similarly for $t_u$ except the flow hinders the velocity of sound, which is there's a minus...

Here's my question, why is the flow velocity $u$ multiplied by $cosθ$? if this is to do with trigonometry, isn't the flow adjacent to the velocity of sound? perhaps I'm missing something very simple here.

[Images and formulas referenced from this website](https://www.efunda.com/designstandards/sensors/flowmeters/flowmeter_ustt.cfm)

Answer (score 1):

Because the sound is slowed down (or likewise sped up) only in the direction of flow. So in order to subtract (or add) the speed of sound and the speed of the media, both quantities need to be in the same direction. The cosine gives you the component of sound velocity in the flow direction.

BTW time of flight is only one part of the equation to determine the flow velocity. You may be able to assume radially symmetric laminar flow and use D in your diagram. But to get accurate flow you also need to know (1) gas composition and (2) gas temperature.

Comment: Actually $ ucos \theta$  is the component of the flow velocity along the direction of propagation of sound.